# aoColumns of datatables are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

Please find attached the application picture, where the column ORDER ID is not showing, and instead of that, is showing the PLUS sign. So all the columns should shift for one to the right.

[ajax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kTaQ.png)
And all the time when I run the application it shows me this error message:

> DataTables warning (table id = 'companies'): Added data (size 3) does not match known number of columns (4)

```js
   var oTable;
    $('#companies tbody td img').live('click', function () {
    var nTr = this.parentNode.parentNode;
    if (this.src.match('details_close')) {
    /* This row is already open - close it */
    this.src = "/Content/images/details_open.png";
    oTable.fnClose(nTr);
    }
    else {
    /* Open this row */
    this.src = "/Content/images/details_close.png";
    var orderid = $(this).attr("rel");
    $.get("Me?OrderID=" + orderid, function (detalet) {
    oTable.fnOpen(nTr, detalet, 'details');
    });
    }
    });

    /* Initialize table and make first column non-sortable*/
    oTable = $('#companies').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": 'AjaxHandler',
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "aoColumns":
     [
    { "bSortable": false, 
    "bSearchable": false,
    "fnRender": function (oObj)
     {
    return '<img src="/Content/images/details_open.png" alt="expand/collapse" rel="' + oObj.aData[0] + '" />';
    }
    },
    null,
    null,
    null
    ]
    });
```

```html
 <table id="companies" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> </th>
                <th>Order  ID</th>


                <th>Customer ID</th>
              
                <th>Ship Address</th>
        
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: You should remove the first th tag from your html code or tell dataTables to not use this column. You have more column declared than data.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the column number in the *aoColumns* definition, e.g.:

```
"aoColumnDefs":[
    {
        "mData": null,
        "bSortable": false, 
        "bSearchable": false,
        "fnRender": function (oObj) {
            return '<img src="/Content/images/details_open.png" alt="expand/collapse" rel="' + oObj.aData[0] + '" />';
        }
    },
    { "mData": 0 },
    { "mData": 1 },
    { "mData": 2 },
    { "mData": 3 }
]
```

And the HTML markup:

```
<table id="companies" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Order  ID</th>
            <th>Customer ID</th>             
            <th>Ship Address</th>
            <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is not showing the plus image now , the first column should return the img src="/Content/images/details_open.png

Comment: Please double check if the image under /Content/images/details_open.png is not a plus sign by mistake.

Comment: details_open is a png file of a PLUS and it exists there . How can i show it in the first column , and other columns next.

Comment: It is showing in the first column. You want it to be placed on the right side of the table (the last column)?

Comment: the first column of the table should be the image , then is order id , then is customer id , then is ship address .thats it.

Comment: Ok, I see it now. Please look at the edited answer now :)

Comment: Still the same , please see the picture attached , i have edited the question , to see that i did everything copy paste , but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following structure for `aoColumns`:

```js
"aoColumns": [
    { 
       "mData": 0,
       "bSortable": false, 
       "bSearchable": false,
       "mRender": function (data, type, full){
          return '<img src="/Content/images/details_open.png" alt="expand/collapse" rel="' + data + '" />';
       }
    },
    { "mData": 1 },
    { "mData": 2 },
    { "mData": 3 }
]
```

Use the following HTML markup:

```html
<table id="companies" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Order ID</th>
            <th>Customer ID</th>             
            <th>Ship Address</th>
            <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is not showing the plus image now , the first column should return the  img src="/Content/images/details_open.png

Comment: Still the same , please see the picture attached , i have edited the question , to see that i did everything copy paste , but its not working.

Comment: Please find attached the application picture, where the column 1 with the plus image is not showing , and all the columns should shift for 1 to the right . 

COLUMN 1 IS THE PLUS IMAGE , COLUMN 2 IS THE ORDER ID , COLUMN 3 IS CUSTOMER ID , COLUMN 4 IS SHIP ADDRESS